# Non-sudo location for script

Tags: permissions, scripts, packaging

I'm trying to convert a simple batch script into a package. According to my (limited) understanding of packaging, this would mean that I would store the script in `/usr/bin`.

The problem is, the batch script uses a different sh script stored somewhere else. The sh script cannot be run as a `sudo`, and the sh script needs to read/write to files in the directory of the sh script. What this means is that I need to have a location to store this script (and the files it uses) without requiring `sudo`. Would this be possible?

(BTW, as the script also downloads files to the users home directory (`~`), I can't make someone run the script with `sudo` because file ownership is then incorrectly handled with the downloaded files. Unless that would be fixable.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Manual Execution

You can execute the command using `bash /path/to/your.sh`.  If you set the file as executable ( `chmod +x /path/to/your.sh` ), then you can do `/path/to/your.sh` and it will automatically run under bash.  You will need to make sure your script has a [shebang](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10376206/what-is-the-preferred-bash-shebang).

### $PATH

#### Overview

---

**$PATH** is an environmental variable that lists all of the locations in which you would like to search for binaries when running a command.

This is how `/usr/bin` is used for binaries.

You can see your current $PATH by opening a terminal and running `echo $PATH`.

```
/most/important/path:/less/important/path
```

As the example above reads, the paths have priorities; first searched first.  This means that if there are two versions of a binary, the one in the first path will be used.  Once a binary is found, it stops searching on other directories in your $PATH.

If you attempt to run `banana`, your computer is going to look at `/most/important/path`.  If it finds `banana`, it will run it.  If not, it will continue searching, moving on to `/less/important/path`.

#### Modification

---

To add directories to your user's path, you could add them to your `~/.bashrc` file.  Instead of overwritting and messing up your path, you should append to it.  For example:

```
export $PATH=${PATH}:/new/less/important/directory
```

Or you can prepend to set it as the highest-priority directory:

```
export $PATH=/new/more/important/path:${PATH}
```

**To prevent issues, you should probably only append (first example).**